# mod_rewrite - Don't get a second rule work

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to have a url like this:
`domain.com/css/site.css?test=234`

Rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^css/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).css?count=(.*)$ css.php?f=$1&test=$2
```

But I get every time a 404: Not found (site.css)

If I have a rule like that it works, just without getting the $_GET-Variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^css/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).css$ css.php?f=$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query string is not present in url to be matched by RewriteRule. You need something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} count=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^css/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).css$ css.php?f=$1&test=%1
```

You can read more about `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond

You can see order in which RewriteConds and RewriteRules are executed here
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#InternalRuleset